# Android: how to exit the app when user navigate off the app

Tags: android

I just want to exit the app completely when user press home, or switch to other app. Is there any event I can listen so that I can do the exit code?

Comment: `Activity.onPause()` is called when your activity goes to the background/ user switches to another activity/presses home button.

Comment: why do you want to do this?  It's "anti Android".  Do you exit a web page when you navigate somewhere else?

Comment: do you want to finish() all activity running?

Answer (score 0):

When Home key is pressed you handle like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        finish();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it works fine with me**

```
// clear whole activity stack

    Intent intent = new Intent("clearStackActivity");
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    sendBroadcast(intent);

// start your new activity
Intent intent = new Intent(OrderComplete.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Put these line in onCreate() method of all Activities or if you have any base activity you can put it there , then no need to put in all activities.

```
private KillReceiver clearActivityStack;
clearActivityStack = new KillReceiver();
        registerReceiver(clearActivityStack, IntentFilter.create("clearStackActivity", "text/plain"));
```

put this class in your Base activity

```
private final class KillReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this from [here](http://nisha113a5.blogspot.com/2012/01/intercept-home-key-android.html).

Override below method in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

After overriding above method, now you can easily listen **HOME** Key press in your activity using `onKeyDown()` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
       //The Code Want to Perform. 
    }
});
```

Comment: from the link u mention, it only works prior 4.0.3
I think it is a "bug" actually as google don't intend to let u capture home button anyway :)